# How to Set the WriteHTMLCell height same as the preceding cells TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I wonder how to set the height of the proceeding cells same as the first cell in WriteHTMLCells like this one

[WriteHTMLCell Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5i1i.png)

Here is my Code

```
foreach($infosp as $item) {
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(60,10,'','',$item['output'],1,0);   
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(70,10,'','',$item['indicators'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(70,10,'','',$item['accomplishment'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(12.4,10,'','',$item['rating_quality'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(12.4,10,'','',$item['rating_efficiency'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(12.4,10,'','',$item['rating_timeliness'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(12.4,10,'','',$item['rating_average'],1,0);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(55,10,'','',$item['remarks'],1,1);
    }
```

all I want is how to make all the cell row height the same as the first cell.

Comment: Why don't use one `writeHTMLCell` and use `table` in it?